After upgrading to Debian bookworm - chronyd Fatal error : Not superuser
I get the following error messages when I try to start Chrony:
Sep 04 10:49:10 production systemd[1]: Starting chrony.service - chrony, an NTP client/server...
Sep 04 10:49:10 production chronyd[38659]: 2024-09-04T08:49:10Z Fatal error : Not superuser
Sep 04 10:49:11 production systemd[1]: chrony.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 04 10:49:11 production systemd[1]: chrony.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 04 10:49:11 production systemd[1]: Failed to start chrony.service - chrony, an NTP client/server.
Sep 04 10:49:17 production systemd[1]: Starting chrony.service - chrony, an NTP client/server...
Sep 04 10:49:17 production chronyd[38718]: 2024-09-04T08:49:17Z Fatal error : Not superuser
Sep 04 10:49:17 production systemd[1]: chrony.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 04 10:49:17 production systemd[1]: chrony.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 04 10:49:17 production systemd[1]: Failed to start chrony.service - chrony, an NTP client/server.

This is my SystemD configuation:
# /lib/systemd/system/chrony.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[Unit]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Description=chrony, an NTP client/server                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Documentation=man:chronyd(8) man:chronyc(1) man:chrony.conf(5)                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Conflicts=openntpd.service ntp.service ntpsec.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Wants=time-sync.target                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Before=time-sync.target                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
After=network.target                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
ConditionCapability=CAP_SYS_TIME                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[Service]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Type=forking                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
PIDFile=/run/chrony/chronyd.pid                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/chrony                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
User=_chrony                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
# Daemon is started as root, but still sandboxed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
ExecStart=!/usr/sbin/chronyd $DAEMON_OPTS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_AUDIT_CONTROL CAP_AUDIT_READ CAP_AUDIT_WRITE                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_BLOCK_SUSPEND CAP_KILL CAP_LEASE CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE                                                                                                                                                                                                         
CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_MAC_ADMIN CAP_MAC_OVERRIDE CAP_MKNOD CAP_SYS_ADMIN                                                                                                                                                                                                           
CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_SYS_BOOT CAP_SYS_CHROOT CAP_SYS_MODULE CAP_SYS_PACCT                                                                                                                                                                                                         
CapabilityBoundingSet=~CAP_SYS_PTRACE CAP_SYS_RAWIO CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG CAP_WAKE_ALARM                                                                                                                                                                                                   
DeviceAllow=char-pps rw                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DeviceAllow=char-ptp rw                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DeviceAllow=char-rtc rw                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DevicePolicy=closed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
LockPersonality=yes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=yes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
NoNewPrivileges=yes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PrivateTmp=yes
ProcSubset=pid
ProtectControlGroups=yes
ProtectHome=yes
ProtectHostname=yes
ProtectKernelLogs=yes
ProtectKernelModules=yes
ProtectKernelTunables=yes
ProtectProc=invisible
ProtectSystem=strict
# Used for gps refclocks
ReadWritePaths=/run
RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_INET AF_INET6 AF_UNIX
RestrictNamespaces=yes
RestrictSUIDSGID=yes
SystemCallArchitectures=native
SystemCallFilter=~@cpu-emulation @debug @module @mount @obsolete @raw-io @reboot @swap
 
ConfigurationDirectory=chrony
RuntimeDirectory=chrony
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0700
# See dumpdir in chrony.conf(5)
RuntimeDirectoryPreserve=restart
StateDirectory=chrony
StateDirectoryMode=0750
LogsDirectory=chrony
LogsDirectoryMode=0750

# Adjust restrictions for /usr/sbin/sendmail (mailonchange directive)
NoNewPrivileges=no
ReadWritePaths=-/var/spool
RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_NETLINK

[Install]
Alias=chronyd.service
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# /etc/systemd/system/chrony.service.d/no_ipv6.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/chronyd -4

That is my chrony.conf:
confdir /etc/chrony/conf.d
sourcedir /run/chrony-dhcp
sourcedir /etc/chrony/sources.d

pool 2.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
keyfile /etc/chrony/chrony.keys
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/chrony.drift
logdir /var/log/chrony
maxupdateskew 100.0
hwclockfile /etc/adjtime
rtcsync
makestep 1 3

ntsdumpdir /var/lib/chrony
leapsectz right/UTC

I can't find where the problem is - I assume some capability problem. Has anyone had the same problem and been able to solve it somehow? Any help or advice would be highly appreciated.
